# How to display taxonomy field value in paragraph twig file?

Tags: 9

How to display role taxonomy field value in `paragraph--user-category.html.twig` file?
Field structure: field_role-> role taxonomy field.

I can print by `{{ content.field_role | raw }}` But I need to display value text only.

I tried below the code and not working. Please advise.
`{{ paragraph.field_role.entity.value }}`

Printed value: `{{ dump(paragraph.field_role) }}`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried below the code and not working. Please advise.
>
> `{{ paragraph.field_role.entity.value }}`

You say you need to display a value text only, but the referenced taxonomy term entity `paragraph.field_role.entity` doesn't have a `.value`. Taxonomy terms have a name:

```
{{ paragraph.field_role.entity.getname }}
```

You can get the `.id` as well and any field value `.field_foo.value`.

### Translation

If you have a multilingual site you need to translate the referenced entities:

```
{{ paragraph.field_role.entity|translation.getname }}
```

Install [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) in this case.

See https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/-/blob/3.x/docs/cheat-sheet.md#entity-translation

Comment: `getname` working fine. Thanks!